# Replacement Strings Not Showing Up In Events From Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I'm using powershell to look at event logs using `Get-WinEvent`. For some reason, the `ReplacementStrings` attribute of the events won't show up for me. I'm very stumped on this because it seems to show up for everyone else on the internet. It will show up using `Get-EventLog` but not `Get-WinEvent`. Is there something I have to enable for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `Get-WinEvent` returns a ReplacementStrings property. Instead replacement strings are return in another array property unfortunately called "Properties"

To demonstrate:

```
$MyEvent = Get-WinEvent -LogName application | Select-Object -First 1
$MyEvent.Properties
```

It shouldn't matter how you are filtering either. What I usually do is pull back a sample of the event(s) I'm interested in then examine the properties collection.  If you want to flatten the object you can use `Select-Object` to add calculated properties that have the values of the interesting elements from properties collection.

```
$MyEvent = 
Get-WinEvent -LogName application | 
Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Property1'; Expression = { $_.Properties[0] }}
```

You would obviously want to add filtering otherwise the `[0]` element will be different for each event.  Nevertheless, the above will add a property to the object named Property1 the value will be the from the first element in the properties collection.